# twitter4j 3.0.3 twitter.updateStatus(msg) does not work

Tags: twitter4j

I'm updating an a project that uses twitter api v1 to v1.1, I realised that the application is not sharing to twitter anymore. I did some research and I updated the code to reflect the new authentication mechanism

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret(ConsumerSecret)
      .setOAuthAccessToken(oAuthAccessToken)
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(oAuthAccessTokenSecret)
      .setHttpRetryCount(2)
      .setHttpRetryIntervalSeconds(2);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance(); 
twitter.addRateLimitStatusListener(rateLimitStatusListener);
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusMsg);
```

The application does not throw any exception anymore but it does tell me that the statusMsg been sent but when I check the twitter account itself I cannot see the tweet. I went back and I added the same status again and the program threw an exception with the cause being that the message is duplicated which means it's there somewhere but the twitter account does not show it. Am I missing anything here?
The exception is

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ab8], statusCode=403, message=Status is a duplicate, code=187, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1871)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:241)
at myClass(TwitterMessage.java:130)
at (DefaultTwitterSocialNetworkApi.java:433)
at myClass(ActivityService.java:433)
at myClass(ActivityService.java:389)
at myClass(UserCommentResource.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myClass(myClass.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myClass(myClass.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myClass(myClass.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**UPDATE:**
I discovered the bug I shoul have added

```
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(userAccessToken);
```

without this line the application sends the tweet to the account that owns the application.

Comment: hi, how do you define the userAccessToken, i.e. String userAccessToken = "2342343252353";? I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Seems like as of today (jan 14) this error is also thrown, when not using a ssl connection. 
Actually the error message is a bit different, as it doesn't clearly state that this is a duplicate status. But the Message contains two ErrorCodes, one of them links here.

Anyway, See [REST API, regarding 403 error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130292/rest-api-regarding-403-error-code/21134302#21134302) for possible solution (enable SSL, use latest twitter4j).